# Replace substring with result from subsquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `messages` table with fields (id, text).
I have a CSV file (boilerplate strings) which is loaded into another temporary table `tmp_import` with field (txt).

Both `messages.text` and `tmp_import` are strings. `messages` can contain boilerplate while `tmp_import` are all boilerplate strings which I intend to search for occurrences of.

A use case is:

- Scan through the rows in `tmp_import`, for each row: (i) search the `messages` table for all occurrences and replace the substring with space ("") character.

I've loaded the CSV into a temporary table but stuck on how to achieve the replace with a subquery.

```
    UPDATE messages
    SET text = REPLACE (text, 'string_to_replace', '')
    WHERE text IN  (SELECT txt 
             FROM tmp_import tmp
             WHERE messages.text LIKE CONCAT('%', tmp.txt, '%'));
```

Any clue on how I can get the `string_to_replace` to take its value from the `txt` in the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where exists` if sub query satisfies the `where` clause

```
UPDATE messages
SET text = REPLACE (text, 'string_to_replace', '')
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tmp_import tmp
              WHERE messages.text LIKE CONCAT('%', tmp.txt, '%'));
```

or use join to get value from tmp_import

```
UPDATE messages m
JOIN tmp_import tmp ON m.text LIKE CONCAT('%', tmp.txt, '%')
SET m.text = REPLACE (m.text, tmp.txt, '')
```

Comment: Thanks, it satisfies the `where` clause, the challenge is `string_to_replace`, I need it to be dynamic and not hard coded. It should be dependent on the string result from the subquery.

Comment: @Ade see second approach in an answer with join clause

Comment: Awesome, let me give it a try.

Comment: @Ade make sure you perform this **first on test data**

Comment: Do you have any tips on speeding this up, the `messages` table can contain up to 500,000 rows

Comment: @Ade i am not sure about the performance for this string based comparison its better if you could ask new question with a table definitions and include [EXPLAIN Plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)  of query so that SO users can have a better look

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE messages
SET text = REPLACE (text, tmp.txt, '')
FROM messages
INNER JOIN tmp_import tmp ON messages.text LIKE CONCAT('%', tmp.txt, '%')
```

Comment: How can I get `string_to_replace` to be dynamic, based on  each string result from the inner join?